# Using words "again" and "anymore" in a specific example

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Imagine because of a severe nightmare you wake up at night. I was wondering if someone could let me know which choice works in the self-made sentence below to fill in the blank:

> - I woke up abruptly from deep sleep last night and couldn’t get back to sleep..........
>
> **a)** again
>
> **b)** anymore

Comment: You don't actually need a word in the blank space but if you really want a word there my choice would be *anymore*.

Comment: @Chris - Interesting; my first choice would be _again_.

Comment: @JR - hmm, yes you can use either choice but it is interesting as it is down to personal choice on what "sounds" correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some contexts where both words can be used to indicate something never happened again. For example, when announcing their intent to quit smoking, someone might say:

> I'm not going to smoke anymore.

or:

> I'm not going to smoke again.

Both of those sentences work fine.

However, sometimes the words don't function as exact synonyms, and the sentence needs to be tweaked if you are going to use one instead of the other. For example, I might say:

> Bob doesn't work here anymore.

In that sentence, I can't really substitute *anymore* with *again*. However, if Bob got fired, I suppose I could say:

> Bob won't work here again.

And when dealing with something in the positive instead of the negative, *anymore* can't be used. For example, if I say:

> Teresa sprained her ankle again.

I can't make a substitution and say:

> Teresa sprained her ankle anymore.

---

In your particular example, if you're telling someone about your nightmare the next morning, either of these work fine:

> I woke up abruptly from deep sleep last night and couldn’t get back to sleep again.
>
> I woke up abruptly from deep sleep last night and couldn’t sleep anymore.

(For some reason, I prefer *again* when *get back to* is used, and *anymore* when it isn't, but that's just a personal preference. I can't think of a grammatical justification for it.)